# HTML-CSS overlay with centered elements

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple full-screen overlay with a loader image and text in the center. I have some problems with the text. I want the image to be **ABOVE** the text. Can you help me with this?

```js
.loader - overlay {
  -ms - opacity: 0.9;
  background: #444;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.loader-content {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.loader-center {
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader-text {
  color: # FFF;
  font - size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="loadingOverlay" class="loader-overlay">
  <div class="loader-content loader-center">
    <img src="http://www.mysarkarinaukri.com/images/loadingBar.gif" class="loader-center" alt="" />
    <div class="loader-center loader-text">Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLz7wgvs/2/

It should look like:

```
                               [-------------loader here-------------]
           Loader text (plz wait, etc.) in one line, both centered horizontally and vertically
```

Comment: Please edit your existing question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.loader-text`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your current .loader-content class and replace it with what you have in .loader-center, followed by simply centering the text of .loader-text, you'll achieve what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/bLz7wgvs/10/

```
.loader-content {
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader-text {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The loader image you are using has a fair bit of transparent space in it, so the text ends up a bit lower than what you might want. To fix that, you have to remove the .loader-center class from everything but the text, and then add the following css properties to it:

```
.loader-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle of what that looks like:
http://jsfiddle.net/bLz7wgvs/11/

What we're doing here is first centering the container that holds the image and text, then we're positioning the text absolute *relative to its parent* to move the text closer to the loader..

Answer (score -1):

Add:

```
.loader-text {
   margin-top: 30px;
   width: 165px;
}
```